# Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String' , how to fix this issue?

Tags: ios, swift

A struct contains this line: `public var allergies: [String]?`  which is called using `newValue?.allergies`, also this line needs to unchanged.

I'm trying to do that allergies only need to accept one `String` item, and it doesn't need to worry about parsing an array of multiple items:

```
if let currentAllergies = newValue?.allergies {
   allergies = currentAllergies  //Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String'
} else {
   allergies = "" 
}
```

I tried so many things, I tried unwrapping the variable but no luck. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try` allergies.first` to get the first element, at the moment it is an array.

Comment: should have been `if let currentAllergies = newValue?.allergies.first`

Comment: Do you want all the allergies in the array concatenated somehow or just the first one?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

When changing array of strings to a single string you need to also explain what should the end result as a string be. Is it for a display or is it only for data storage.

Array of strings means you have

```
let allergies: [String] = [
    "Skin allergy",
    "Sun allergy",
    "Food allergy"
]
```

and this may be presented as a single string for instance with coma separated sum of all items like

```
"Skin allergy, Sun allergy, Food allergy"
```

To do so you can easily use a method `joined`.

```
let allergyString = allergies.joined(separator: ", ")
```

So in your case you can do

```
allergies = newValue?.allergies.joined(separator: ", ") ?? ""
```

If you needed to reverse you could get components separated by your separator

```
let allergyArray: [String] = allergyString.components(separatedBy: ", ")
```

But you need to be very careful doing this because your separator may be part of your original data. For instance imagine to have the following:

```
let allergies: [String] = [
    "Skin allergy",
    "Severe, critical and fatal food allergy"
]
```

Joining it would produce `"Skin allergy, Severe, critical and fatal food allergy"`. But getting back components will split it to

```
let allergies: [String] = [
    "Skin allergy",
    "Severe",
    "critical and fatal food allergy"
]
```

To solve this reverse issue you will need to take a look into some coding tools such as JSON and base64. But I hope that joining a string will already solve your concrete problem.